# Creating links using root url within Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I'm within a Razor view in an Asp.net Core app. I need to set links within the page. The problem is that this view belongs to a `ProductController` and the result of the link below is `https://localhost:44390/product/test`

```
 <a href="test" class="index-az__list-link">Name</a>
```

The links need to be like this:  `https://localhost:44390/test/` and not `https://localhost:44390/product/test` Which is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: I am confused, is https://localhost:44390/test/ a valid URL? The controller is missing from the URL, how would you route this URL to Product controller?

Comment: I have custom routes for that, that's a valid url,

Comment: Still new to asp.net core(still reading up on it), but cant you use @Url.ActionLink("ViewName","Controller") from the old mvc?

Answer (score 0):

So writing the link this way produces the output I want to:

```
 <a href='@($"{Context.Request.Scheme}://{Context.Request.Host.Value}/test")' class="index-az__list-link">Name</a>
```